# WebAPI when running PUT method with Postman is fine, running with API controller will fail

Tags: c#, webapi

I'm in pretty big trouble. I don't understand why. When I execute PUT method on my websevice, the system returns "200 ok", but when doing by API, I get "401 unauthorized" error. here is my API code.

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://....../api/books/" + GetIdUser(cid));// dan ma code vao day getcard
        request.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer FO_KO7XTNe6tam...FG7L5gbGObl4z");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var a = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();// chuoi gia tri can gan vao trong book
        var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PUT2Bien.Book>(a);

        //string datetime1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://......../api/allocations/5eaa75c18d64e05fde5fd540");
        request1.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        request1.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer FO_KO7XTNe6tam...FG7L5gbGObl4z");
        var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1);
        string b = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();// chuoi gia tri can gan vao trong book

        try
        {
            var content1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PUT2Bien.Root>(b);
            for (int i = 0; i < content1.seats.Count; i++)
            {
                if (content1.seats[i]._id == "5eb3c344a9e9486ebb3450cd")//moi may tinh cai dat se co 1 id khac nhau//
                {
                    if (content1.seats[i].book == null)
                    {
                        content1.seats[i].book = content;
                    }
                }
            }
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content1,Formatting.Indented);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response3 = await client.PutAsync("https://......./api/allocations/5eaa75c18d64e05fde5fd540", httpContent);
            MessageBox.Show("" + response3.StatusCode);
        }
```

- this is my json string after executing the command (var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (content1, Formatting.Indented);)

```html
{
  "_id": "5eaa75c18d64e05fde5fd540",
  "account": "demo",
  "name": "院内",
  "image": "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/..../images/demo/allocations/eeb38e0a-3858-4353-b2c3-fbec598d1814.jpg",
  "seats": [
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c344a9e9486ebb3450cd",
      "left": 0.36587301587301585,
      "top": 0.13202256244963739,
      "width": 0.066666666666666707,
      "height": 0.070136986301369858,
      "book": {
        "users": [],
        "tags": [],
        "note": "",
        "_id": "5f9ca83e1249971c625a7981",
        "line": "5c51541c93908265a7668caf",
        "start": "2020-10-31T00:50:00Z",
        "end": "2020-10-31T03:30:00Z",
        "type": "appointment",
        "status": "waiting",
        "card": {
          "recall": {
            "tags": [],
            "users": [],
            "date": "2020-10-20T15:00:00Z"
          },
          "gender": "male",
          "risk": 0,
          "tags": [
            {
              "effect": "blink",
              "_id": "5bfa0966b13b093268c0235c",
              "name": "SET",
              "color": "#ffa000",
              "account": "demo",
              "icon": "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/..../images/demo/tags/f2d0eb03-2996-48f6-90d0-5aec98912059.png"
            }
          ],
          "users": [
            {
              "admin": false,
              "_id": "5a55d0ed0ddfaa11476df01a",
              "updatedAt": "2018-01-10T08:38:05.622Z",
              "createdAt": "2018-01-10T08:38:05.622Z",
              "name": "高田",
              "color": "#ff9800",
              "username": "",
              "account": "demo",
              "group": "DH",
              "hidden": false,
              "kana": "たかだ",
              "dentistCode": "102",
              "nopass": true
            }
          ],
          "relations": [],
          "_id": "5a55d12315e0200f04ec1e90",
          "account": "demo",
          "cid": "3004",
          "createdAt": "2018-01-10T08:38:59.924Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-10-21T02:39:17.022Z",
          "name": "波多野 亮",
          "kana": "ハタノ リョウ",
          "email": "hatano_ryou@example.com",
          "birthday": "1952/12/12",
          "address": "大阪府",
          "phone": "090-982-2851"
        },
        "account": "demo",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-30T23:56:46.068Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-31T07:24:09.494Z",
        "__v": 42,
        "logs": {
          "waiting": "2020-10-31T03:15:24.184Z"
        },
        "startedAt": "2020-10-31T00:47:58.354Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c352a9e9486ebb3450d3",
      "left": 0.46825396825396826,
      "top": 0.13477303250067149,
      "width": 0.066666666666666652,
      "height": 0.064636046199301661,
      "book": null
    },
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c356a9e9486ebb3450d5",
      "left": 0.6253968253968254,
      "top": 0.33693258125167874,
      "width": 0.049206349206349254,
      "height": 0.10314262691377923,
      "book": null
    },
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c35aa9e9486ebb3450d8",
      "left": 0.36507936507936506,
      "top": 0.55146924523233953,
      "width": 0.063492063492063489,
      "height": 0.07701316142895509,
      "book": null
    },
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c360a9e9486ebb3450dc",
      "left": 0.46904761904761905,
      "top": 0.55146924523233953,
      "width": 0.063492063492063489,
      "height": 0.07701316142895509,
      "book": null
    },
    {
      "cleaning": false,
      "_id": "5eb3c365a9e9486ebb3450e1",
      "left": 0.62777777777777777,
      "top": 0.76188020413644908,
      "width": 0.046825396825396881,
      "height": 0.10451786193929624,
      "book": null
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-04-30T06:52:49.461Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-10-31T07:24:09.585Z"
}
```

Can anyone help me, thanks so much!

Comment: I have an error at the line: var response3 = await client.PutAsync ("https: //.../api/allocations/5eaa75c18d64e05fde5fd540", httpContent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the authorization header:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
var response3 = await client.PutAsync("https://......./api/allocations/5eaa75c18d64e05fde5fd540", httpContent);
```

You are adding it by the requests to all three other cases, but not the last one.

If you have the same Bearer for all call, you can do it once at the start of your function, with no need to add it on each different request.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, I got it. This issue took me a whole day, thank you very much! @

Comment: Don't forget to accept question that resolved your issue. Cheers